# Yosemite Server, adaptive firewall not stopping screensharingd attempts?

Tags: macos, osx-server, firewall

I'm not certain if the Adaptive Firewall in Yosemite Server 4.0 is just not working or just not working for screensharingd.  I have a Mac mini Server in a colo and get lots of attempts at screensharing.  So I turned on the adaptive firewall as per Apple docs and it does not seem to be doing anything.

Whats my next step?

Answer (score 1):

The only sure solution I know of for this is to configure VPN on the server then lock down port 5900 on the WAN interface. That will kill the attempts for screen sharing from the public side but allow it when you VPN into the server.

If the port is open on the public-facing WAN side, you can be sure that the port-scanners are going to find it and attempt getting in.